# The output of my stargazer table is empty. Why

Tags: r, stargazer

Data: https://www.kaggle.com/jessemostipak/hotel-booking-demand?select=hotel_bookings.csv.

booking <- read_csv(".../hotel_bookings.csv")

summary(booking)

stargazer(booking, type = "html", header =F,
digits = 2, out = "Output/Plots/Booking_output.html")

The output however is the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPeIT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`stargazer(as.data.frame(booking), type = "html", header =F, digits = 2, out = "Output/Plots/Booking_output.html")`

It expects a data frame, not a tibble, which is produced by `read_csv`.